# How to set output path in react-native-image-resizer?

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, image-processing

I'm trying to resize an image using react-native-image-resizer in android and it's working fine but I want to set an output path and in the documentation, it's not clearly mentioned how to set an output path

```
import ImageResizer from 'react-native-image-resizer';

ImageResizer.createResizedImage(path, maxWidth, maxHeight, compressFormat, quality, rotation, outputPath)
  .then(response => {
    // response.uri is the URI of the new image that can now be displayed, uploaded...
    // response.path is the path of the new image
    // response.name is the name of the new image with the extension
    // response.size is the size of the new image
  })
  .catch(err => {
    // Oops, something went wrong. Check that the filename is correct and
    // inspect err to get more details.
  });
```

here is my code

```
launchImageLibrary({mediaType: 'photo'}, (img) => {
 
       ImageResizer.createResizedImage(
          img.uri, // Image path
          img.width, //width
          img.height, //height
          img.fileName.split('.')[1], //image format
          100, // quality
          0, // rotation
          outputPath,// I need help here
        )
          .then((response) => {
          

        var image = new FormData();
        image.append('file', response);
        image.append('filetype', 'IMG');
        
       // uploading image
        axios({
          method: 'POST',
          url: `${API_URL}`,
          data: image,
          headers: {
            mimeType: 'multipart/form-data',
          },
        })
          .then((res) => {
            alert(JSON.stringify(res));
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            alert(`erro ${err}`);
          });
        
      });   
   });
```

[link to documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-image-resizer)

I need help with the syntax. How to create a hidden folder in the Android device and set it as a outputPath.

Comment: `ImageResizer.createResizedImage(path, maxWidth, maxHeight, compressFormat, quality, rotation, outputPath)` Well... I see `path` and `outputPath`. And you?

Comment: @blackapps I didn't get you? but I'm looking for outputPath I don know to set it?

Comment: Well how do you set `path`? Show how you call that function now.

Comment: @blackapps now I added my actual code.

Comment: Well to which path do you wanna set it? Where do you wanna store the result? We cannot decide that for you.

Comment: @blackapps any out path in the android or we can create new folder as well or set it as output path.

Comment: Well try it out. Try all. What is the problem with experimenting a bit?

Comment: @blackapps what do I write? how do I write? what's the syntax? how do I create a new folder inside my phone or set it as outputPath? can you help me with the syntax?

Comment: @HemendraKhatik did you resolve it? having the same issue now. I don't actually know if which `mobile device` path to put. I tried `file:///data/user/0/com.testapp/cache/` but it says `No such file or directory`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue so I dig down to the source.

I just put `undefined` value in `outputPath` param as indicated in their sample.

https://github.com/bamlab/react-native-image-resizer/blob/master/example/App.js